# slim 2 flushing buffer

Tags: php, twig

I'm writing an app with Slim2 Framework but I have 1 problem that I don't know how to resolve.

I've wrote a personal class that elaborate some data and it takes 5 minutes to finish.

```
class MyClass
{
  function a(){
  //some code
    for ($i = 0; $i < $n; $i++) {
      //start cycle 
      //some code
      flush();
      ob_flush();
    }
    return $array //an array with some data
  }
 }
```

This function is run in my app in Slim2

```
$app->get('/myapp/', function () use ($app, $i ){
 $app->myclass->a()

   $app->render('mypage.twig', array(
     'someVariables' => $app->myclass->someVariables,
   ));
})->name('myapp');
```

and the variable *someVariables* it's managed into twig template.

The problem is that I can't render partial result as I can do with *flush()* and *ob_flush()*. I'd like to render the result at least at the end of every cycle for, instead I get the full result when the function is terminated.

I've tried with *{% flush %}* into twig template, but I have the same problem.

Is it possible to manipulate output buffering into slim2 so I can print piece of page instead of waiting for entire page built?